# Como obtener el valor de un input que se encuentra dentro de una tabla con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de titulación y tengo el siguiente inconveniente.
Tengo una tabla html que trae datos de una bd y una de las columnas tiene un input text donde muestra un dato. El inconveniente que tengo es que al capturar ese dato que se muestra en el input text de la columna de la tabla , al mostrarlo en otro input me muestra la etiqueta input text completa con el dato y yo solo quiero que envíe solo el dato y no la etiqueta.

acá dejo la imagen de la tabla y de como se muestra el dato en el otro input.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los botones son los que muestran las ventanas que mostraran el dato del input text en otro input.
acá dejo la imagen de como se ve el dato en el otro input.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me trae el input y si yo quito el input de la tabla ahì me trae bien el dato, pero y necesito ese input y lo que necesito es que al capturar el dato sólo capture el valor del input y no la etiqueta.

Acá dejo el código jquery con el que capturo el dato.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#tablaGuiasVuelo tbody tr ").on ("click",function (event) {
var id2= $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
$(#idAwb).val(id2);
});
});
</script>
```

el idAwb Es el id con el que le paso el dato al input de la otra ventana.

```
<input type="text" id="idAwb" class="form-control">
```

Que debería cambiar en el código de javascript para que solo me envíe el valor del input y no la etiqueta input completa?

Comment: Prueba con `var id2= $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").val();`

Comment: Hola, acabo de probar y no envía el valor. El otro input se muestra sin dato

Comment: Como lo podría hacer?

Comment: Puedes probar con var id2= $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text()

Comment: Hola compañero no me funciona de esa manera , el input se muestra en blanco.

Comment: hola aun no puedo traer solo el dato, me podrían ayudar por favor

Comment: Por favor me podrían ayudar con este tema. Lo he intentado de todas las maneras y no funciona. Como se podria hacer para que se muestre solo el valor y no el codigo html del input?

Comment: Hola estimados, me podrían ayudar con este tema por favor, he intentado hacerlo de muchas formas y aun no consigo que se muestre solo el valor del input text que está en la tabla. Por favor si me pudieran sugerir alguna otra forma para este caso.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo simplificar el código, y trabajar con el atributo `data`.

Quizás más que simplificarlo, es hacerlo más fácil de leer.

**Te adjunto un ejemplo:** *Testado*

Este ejemplo lo puedes usar siempre y cuando esté en tu mano poder editar la tabla.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".add").on ("click",function () {
      var id2 = $(this).data('id');
      var value = $('#'+id2).val();
      $('#idAwb').val(value);
    });

  });
</script>

<input type="text" id="idAwb" class="form-control" value="">


<table id="tablaGuiasVuelo">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ><input id="1" value="ccelda_1_1"  /></td><td>celda_2_1</td><td><button  data-id="1" class="add">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><input id="2" value="celad_1_2"  /></td><td>celda_2_2</td><td><button  data-id="2" class="add">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

## Sin atributo data

He testado tú código y funciono correctamente...

La única diferencia es que en el tuyo `$(#idAwb).val(id2);` **Le faltan las comillas**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#tablaGuiasVuelo tbody tr ").on ("click",function (event) {
var id2 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
$('#idAwb').val(id2);
});
});

</script>

<input type="text" id="idAwb" class="form-control" value="">


<table id="tablaGuiasVuelo">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ><input value="ccelda_1_1"  /></td><td>celda_2_1</td><td><button  class="add" id="1">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><input  value="celad_1_2"  /></td><td>celda_2_2</td><td><button  class="add" id="2">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```